# Querying A Specific Git Branch in TFS 2015 with Rest API v2.0

Tags: powershell, tfs-2015, visual-studio-2019

I have a list of git repositories in TFS 2015 that I have accessed with the TFS Rest API v. 2.0 in Powershell, and I would like only to return the most recent release branch for each, however the response still returns the 'defaultBranch' branch property (an earlier release).

I have tried setting the value of the 'versionDescriptor.version' uri parameter to a regular expression that matches this branch.  Our release branches take the generic pattern, "releases/x.x.xx," so my regex would need to find the highest digit for each 'x.'

```
$tfsUrl = 'http://tfs.infosys.com:8080/tfs/'
$collectionName = 'BCSA'
$collectionUrl =  "$($tfsUrl)$($collectionName)"
$getProjectsUrl = "$($collectionUrl)/BHBs/_apis/git/repositories/?api-version=2.0"
$getItemsURL = "$($collectionUrl)/BHBs/_apis/git/repositories/" 
[datetime]$dateTime = Get-Date -Format u
$refDate = $dateTime.AddYears(-2)
[regex]$branchName = "^releases/d[3].\d[0-9].\d[0-9]$"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri $getProjectsUrl

foreach ($repository in $response.value)
{
    $itemsURI = "$($getItemsURL)$($repository.id)" + "/items?                      
recursionLevel=full&versionDescriptor.versionType=branch&versionDescriptor.version=$branchName&latestProcessedChange=true&includeContent=true&api-version=2.0"
    $repoResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri $itemsURI 
    $repoResponse = $repoResponse.value | Where-Object {$_.gitObjectType -eq 
    "blob" -and [datetime]$_.latestProcessedChange.author.date -gt $refDate} | 
    Select-Object -Property Path, latestProcessedChange 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[regex]$branchName = "^releases/d[3].\d[0-9].\d[0-9]$"` Seems your code is just pulling branch based on a specific name version name `releases/x.x.xx`.

In my case I tried to handle this:

```
VssBasicCredential credintials = new VssBasicCredential(String.Empty, "YOUR SECRET CODE HERE");
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://yourserverurl.visualstudio.com/"), credintials);
GitHttpClient client = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();

List<GitRepository> repositories = await client.GetRepositoriesAsync(true); // or use GetRepositoryAsync()
var repo = repositories.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == "Some.Repo.Name");

GitVersionDescriptor descriptor = new GitVersionDescriptor()
{
    VersionType = GitVersionType.Branch,
    Version = "develop",
    VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None
};

List<GitItem> items = await client.GetItemsAsync(repo.Id, scopePath: "/", recursionLevel: VersionControlRecursionType.Full, versionDescriptor: descriptor);
```

Then if you will try directly to get contents of an item `client.GetItemTextAsync(repo.Id, item.Path)` you will receive an error in case when the branch isn't default. **Just provide GitVersionDescriptior again.**

```
GitVersionDescriptor commitDescriptior = new GitVersionDescriptor()
{
    VersionType = GitVersionType.Commit,
    Version = item.CommitId,
    VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None
};

Stream stream = await client.GetItemTextAsync(repo.Id, item.Path, download: true, versionDescriptor: commitDescriptior)
```